# Flutter MySql Connection with Plesk Server MariaDB

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart, mariadb

i got a Problem with a MYSQL Server Connection, i looked to much Videos on Youtube but its making this only with Localhost, i got a Plesk Hosting and a IP Adress, i tested the mysql1 Package from pub.dev but its not also working im getting Problem as ,
[image]

has anybody know how can i connect a Database and get Data from Row ?
I changed also Plesk Settings as Remote Connection Allowed to Database.
Thanks.